# CountIf Horizontal

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

So I have a formula
Countif() to check if there is a duplicate data entered,

My problem is how to select a cell horizontally.
I like to select cell A up to cell H.
And check using the Countif().

As of now I only Check the two cells here is my formula:
=COUNTIF($A:$A, $B1)=1

(The =1 is for checking only, if there is a duplicate data)

It only checks the cell a and b. I want it to atleast check the cells up to cell H. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Select A:H and create a conditional formatting rule using the 'Format only unique or duplicate values, Duplicate' option.

[image]

As this site is for professional and enthusiastic programmers, here's some code to perform the action.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
    With Worksheets(1).Range("A:H")
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        With .FormatConditions.AddUniqueValues
            .DupeUnique = xlDuplicate
            .Interior.Color = vbRed
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok, I meant I wanted to vote your answer up twice - for the two solutions you gave as the formatting one is nicely “out of the box” and gives a useful feedback.

Comment: If for some reason OP still wants to use `COUNTIF` (or wants to know the solution using it), then something like that will do I guess https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEYKI.png

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
=COUNTIF($A:$H, condition) > 1
```

The first argument is the range to count over. The second argument is the condition.

For a single row over those columns e.g.

```
=COUNTIF($A1:$H1, condition) > 1
```

Comment: I just want to find out where is the duplicate data.
for example in cell a I input John
and for cell c I input John again
and for cell h I input John again...

Comment: btw, I'm using a Conditional Formatting.

Comment: Hey Solar Mike, I haven't try it yet, but can you give me a starting point through using that?

Comment: Like how Jeeped?

Comment: Raphael - please can you show some sample data and expected output? Also, what does not working mean?

Comment: Did you perhaps mean for a single row?

Comment: Okay, picture this out so I have an event worksheet, 
and there is an 8 columns, each column is the name of the event 
and below that name of the event there is a drop down 
I use, data validation list and there are only two values in that, 
one is "Attending" and the other one is "Not Attending".

What I want to achieve is I will limit the user to choose other events once he / she attend one of the events. like i will change the color of the cell to red, meaning he / she will be attending a two event, which is not possible.

Comment: edit that info into your question so everyone can see it easily.